SQL/BQ Error: there is no matching signature
Im trying to query a table in BQ. I keep getting an error that "there is no matching signature = for argument type string." Its weird because the data formats are all strings
'''Select city
From city_tables
Where city = 'nyc'
'''

I have replicated your case it looks like your query is conflicting with the data type that is in the schema:

Can you try checking again your schema or post the details of the table?
